# AWS Lambda - re.sub in Python - remove Brackets at end of line

Tags: python, python-re

I need to convert Hive DDL's to Redshift DDL. I am utilizing re.sub in my code to perform conversion.
I am unable to substitute ')' at the end of line.

Eg:-

```
"ci_stage" : "varchar(30))
"target_manager_id" : "bigint)
```

Desired output:-

```
"ci_stage" : "varchar(30)"
"target_manager_id" : "bigint"
```

I have tried:

```
modified_line113 = re.sub('[)]$','"', modified_line112)
modified_line113 = re.sub(r"\)$", '"', modified_line112)
```

They are not working. What is the easiest way to remove character ")" at end of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern uses an anchor to assert the end of the string, so you need to add the multi line flag `re.M` to `re.sub` for multiple replacements.

```
import re

modified_line112 = """"ci_stage" : "varchar(30))
"target_manager_id" : "bigint)"""

modified_line113 = re.sub(r"\)$", '"', modified_line112, 0, re.M)
print(modified_line113)
```

Output

```
"ci_stage" : "varchar(30)"
"target_manager_id" : "bigint"
```

Comment: The `)` must be replaced by `"` is now done, nice!